# Pick default value of DataPicker Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I have some problems with DataPicker: How i can pick needed value in DatePicker.
example: already picked "1 ITEM" , and needs to pick "2 ITEM" by pressing button. Need to pick item[index+1], how i can do that?

```
func numberOfItemsInPickerView(_ pickerView: AKPickerView) -> Int {

        switch pickerView {
        case yearPickerView:
            return defaultDataSample.years.count
        case monthPickerView:
            return defaultDataSample.months.count
        case quaterPickerView:
            return defaultDataSample.quaters.count
        default:
            return 0
        }
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: AKPickerView, titleForItem item: Int) -> String {

        switch pickerView {
        case yearPickerView:
            return defaultDataSample.years[item]
        case monthPickerView:
            return defaultDataSample.months[item]
        case quaterPickerView:
            return defaultDataSample.quaters[item]
        default:
            return ""
        }

    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: AKPickerView, didSelectItem item: Int) {

        switch pickerView {
        case yearPickerView:
            finantialDataSample.currentYear = Int(defaultDataSample.years[item])

        case monthPickerView:
            finantialDataSample.period = defaultDataSample.months[item]

        case quaterPickerView:
            finantialDataSample.period = defaultDataSample.quaters[item]

        default:
            break
        }
```

Comment: I don't understand, are you to scroll to the next item by code? Your code just presents the pickerview.

Comment: yes, its presents the picker view, how i can scroll to the next item but pressing a button? i don't understand how to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set a variable to remember the last row selected and then move to the next one.

```
var currentRow = 0
func pickerView(_ pickerView: AKPickerView, didSelectItem item: Int) {
    switch pickerView {
         case yearPickerView:
            currentRow = item
         default:
            break
    }
}

func buttonaction() { //Button triggers this
      let nextRow = currentRow + 1
      pickerview.selectRow(nextRow, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
}
```

Let me know if this does not work for you.

Niall

Comment: Yea, it works! Very pleasantly to get a message from the youngest IOS Developer) How old are u?

Comment: for that class of pickerView, named AKPickerView, method calls "scroll"